# If a text is not wrapped in the button then there should be "..." after some text

Tags: html, css, button

I want my button value to be `Entrepreneurship`. Hence, it may not be wrapped in the fixed width button. so What I want is, I want my button value to be `Entrepreneu…` instead of cutting the extra text in button.

Here is the image.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the CSS `text-overflow` property?

Comment: Yeah.. `text-overflow:ellipsis`. Done...  forgot to write `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Do post the code what you have tried!

Comment: It worked. As I have mentioned in comment , that forgot to write `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using these style and you will get an ellipsis:

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

example below:

```css
.truncate {
  width: 75px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<button class="truncate">Entrepreneurship</button>
```